# Scala GroupBy elements inside a nested List

Tags: scala

Suppose I have some class `Info` with many attributes, one being `categories: Option[List[String]`. I have a list of such `Info objects`, eg: `val bigList = (Info1,Info2,Info3)`.

I would like to sort `bigList` by each category of each element:

`sortedList = List((category1,(Info1,Info2,Info3)),(category2,(Info4,Info4)),...)`

and so on.

I've tried using `groupBy` like such:

`val sortedList =  bigList.groupBy(_.categories.getOrElse(""))`

which doesn't work as certain objects have multiple categories, so it groups objects that share certain categories.

Therefore, is it possible to groupBy each category in the categories attribute?

Comment: If you want to sort, then why using `groupBy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to construct a hash map with categories as keys, each entry containing all `Info` objects that contain that particular category.

You can achieve this by taking the `bigList` and for each element construct a tuple with category as first element. Then you can group by that element and, to make things a bit cleaner, iterate through values in order to remove the categories (we're iterating through hash map *values*, so we don't need category here, because it's already present in the corresponding hash map *key*).

Code:

```
case class Info(categories: Option[List[String]], id: String)

val info1 = Info(Some(List("A")), "1")
val info2 = Info(Some(List("A", "B")), "2")
val info3 = Info(Some(List("B", "C")), "3")

val bigList = List(info1, info2, info3)

def getCategories(info: Info): List[(String, Info)] =
  info.categories.getOrElse(List()).map(_-> info)

val result: Map[String, List[Info]] = bigList
  .flatMap(getCategories)
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .view.mapValues(_.map(_._2))
  .toMap

//  HashMap(
//    A -> List(Info(Some(List(A)),1), Info(Some(List(A, B)),2)),
//    B -> List(Info(Some(List(A, B)),2), Info(Some(List(B, C)),3)),
//    C -> List(Info(Some(List(B, C)),3))
//  )
```